# when click button code require to open output on new tab

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i am using apex 18.1 with database 11g in windows, my page has dynamic action, with following Executre java script;

```
apex.navigation.redirect('localhost:1234/reports/rwservlet? server=servername.&report=myrep.rdf&userid=user/pwd@link&desformat=pdf&destype=cache&paramform=no');
```

it works fine when Button press but output (.pdf) opens in same browser tab and i do want it to open in new tab;
please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `apex.navigation.redirect(...)`, try `window.open('...','_blank')`

Comment: did but not working, it behaves same and opens it in same windows and tab

Comment: Did you really add the `'_blank'` part? Because, it does open the contents in a new tab.

Comment: i did this, window.open('localhost:1234/reports/rwservlet? server=servername.&report=myrep.rdf&userid=user/pwd@link&desformat=pdf&destype=cache&paramform=no','_blank');

Comment: Hm, looks OK to me.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it work.